# Multiple view component stick to top on scroll inside ScrollView

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am having a page which consists of 2 different list sections(listComponent1 and listComponent2) and above each list I have created a custom label using  and , and kept the complete section inside ScrollView, now I have a requirement where if the lists are too long whenever I scroll the 2 labels(labelComponent1 and labelComponent2) should stick to the top below header even though the list items goes out of the viewport.

I have tried adding stickyHeaderIndices={[1]} and showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} properties inside ScrollView component, still it didn't work, not sure if I am doing some mistake

Code:

```
  <SafeAreaView>
    <ScrollView alwaysBounceHorizontal={false} horizontal={false} contentContainerStyle={testStyle}>
      {true && <View>
        <labelComponent1 data={test1} />
        <listComponent1 data={testData1} />
        <Spacing />
        <labelComponent2 data={test2} />
        <listComponent2 data={testData2} />
      </View >}
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Don't know exactly what you have in mind but did you try to split your data et use only on SectionList ? https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist.html

Comment: @Fromwood - I am using Draggable Flatlist for both the lists and they consists of some other features as well, so wanted to keep it totally independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}` so the first child will be sticky. but dont wrap the child of `ScrollView` in one `View`. it wrap them into one component so the ScrollView will only have on child. Try this:

```
<SafeAreaView>
   {booleanVar && <ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} horizontal={false}>
        <labelComponent1 data={test1} />
        <listComponent1 data={testData1} />
        <Spacing />
        <labelComponent2 data={test2} />
        <listComponent2 data={testData2} />
    </ScrollView>}
</SafeAreaView>
```